# Angular 4 or 5 - how to get result of this function in my component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I work with Angular 5 (with TypeScript)
I just want to get width and height of an image file (whithout installing a package, I think it's not necessary). I want to get them in variables of my component.
I use in my .ts a function that I used when I worked in javascript and I get yes the width and the height in the function but How can I get them OUT of the function ?? My function doesn't recognize the variables of my component.

Thank you and sorry if you find my question a bit stupid... I work with Angular recently.

Here is my code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-function',
  templateUrl: './test-function.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-function.component.css']
})
export class TestFunctionComponent implements OnInit {

  url: string;
  ratio: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  myFunction() {
    const photo = new Image();
    photo.onload = function() {
      console.log(photo.width + 'x' + photo.height); // here it's ok
      const ratioHere = photo.width % photo.height;
      // return ratioHere ???? because this.ratio of the Component is undefined here
    };
    photo.src = 'https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';

    // this.ratio = ratioHere;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ratio` in your callback. Note that you need an arrow function so `this` is preserved correctly:

```
 photo.onload = () => {
      console.log(photo.width + 'x' + photo.height);
      const ratioHere = photo.width % photo.height;
      this.ratio = ratioHere;
    };
```